# NetworkError: 403 Forbidden accessing websocket in tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, atmosphere, scalatra

I have configured a webapp to run in tomcat7. I connect to it via websocket using scalatra atmoshphere. Everything works fine when both my client and server are on the same machine. But once I tried running the server at a remote location I was not able to get the websocket connection to work. In my Firebug logging I see the messages below. But I cannot see anything in my access log in tomcat. So have no idea what the problem is on the server side and how to rectify.

```
Using URL: ws://myhost:8080/myapp/path/to/atmoshphere-client?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=1.1.0&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Cache-Date=0&Content-Type=application/json&X-atmo-protocol=true

"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://myhost:8080/myapp/path/to/atmoshphere-client?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=1.1.0&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Cache-Date=0&Content-Type=application/json&X-atmo-protocol=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I had a proxy configured in my browser which was what was doing the blocking